# Looping Functionality On Discord Bot Doesn't Work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Whenever I try to use this looping functionality, it gives me an error that has lines that are further than the end of my code. I am fairly new to python and coding in general, but I think this is part of a repository I downloaded. The error code looks like this

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 603, in run
    self._do_run()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 590, in _do_run
    data = self.source.read()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 543, in read
    ret = self.original.read()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 228, in read
    ret = self._stdout.read(OpusEncoder.FRAME_SIZE)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 616, in _call_after
    self.after(error)
  File "main.py", line 242, in play_next_song
    raise VoiceError(str(error))
VoiceError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

My Entire code block is [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/c3b8792a). I am trying to host this discord bot in repl.it, if that has anything to do with it.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: welcome to SO. Please don't post content which is crucial to your question on external websites. Firstly we don't want to force people who want to help you to visit external sites (forcing them to check the domain, etc..) and secondly if this url ever goes offline, this post will be broken for the rest of eternity ;)

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part of the stacktrace is actually the last one:

```
  File "main.py", line 242, in play_next_song
    raise VoiceError(str(error))
VoiceError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

You cannot use the same FFmpegPCMAudio object twice. You have the create a new one.